# Slow video down to a stop gradually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project where a video plays in the background and events need to be fired at certain points in the video. At these points, the video needs to gradually slow down and stop before the event displays.

So far I have made this happen by getting the frame rate and the more it goes up the slower the video playback is, however, it is quite stuttery and jumps into slowing down very fast I would like something smoother. Also currently when you then want to replay the video it falls within the slow down to a stop area of the frames and starts to slow down before starting to play again. I've put in a different video to my actual video as for demo purposes so there is only one event which actually fires in this due to the video being small but there's need to be multiple events at different points in the video.

```js
var currentFrame = $('#currentFrame');
var video = VideoFrame({
  id: 'video',
  frameRate: 29.97,
  callback: function(frame) {
    currentFrame.html(frame);
    if ((frame > 60) && (frame < 135) || (frame > 875) && (frame < 952) || (frame > 1700) && (frame < 1798)) {
      decrease_rate(frame);
    } else {
      reset_frames_rate();
    }
  }
});

$('#play-pause').click(function() {
  ChangeButtonText();
});


window.decrease_rate = decrease_rate;
var frame_on_start = 0,
  frame_rate_dif,
  new_speed;

function decrease_rate(frame) {

  if (frame_on_start == 0) {
    console.log("frame rate reset");
    frame_on_start = frame;
  } else {
    frame_rate_dif = frame - frame_on_start;
    new_speed = 1 - (frame_rate_dif / 100);
    document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = new_speed;
    if (frame_rate_dif > 65) {
      reset_frames_rate();
      video.video.pause();
      video.stopListen();
      $("#play-pause").html('Play');
      show_event();

    }
  }


}


window.show_event = show_event;

function show_event() {
  $('.event1').removeClass('hide_event');

}

window.reset_frames_rate = reset_frames_rate;

function reset_frames_rate() {
  frame_on_start = 0;
  frame_rate_dif = 0;

  document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 1;


}

function ChangeButtonText() {
  if (video.video.paused) {
    video.video.play();
    video.listen('frame');
    $("#play-pause").html('Pause');
    $('.event1').addClass('hide_event');
  } else {
    video.video.pause();
    video.stopListen();
    $("#play-pause").html('Play');
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}

.hide_event {
  display: none;
}

.event1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allensarkisyan/VideoFrame/master/VideoFrame.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <video height="180" width="100%" id="video"> 
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></source>
</video>
  <div id="event1" class="event1 hide_event">
    <p>Display event</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="frame">
  <span id="currentFrame">0</span>
</div>
<div id="controls">
  <button id="play-pause">Play</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is your issue, but consider making an "easing" function to determine the frame rate.

Comment: I think, that for decreasing the stutter you should use avideo with a higher fps rate, and for the part where you want the lower the speed at which the frames drop, you could make a timeout of some sort in your cycle.